# How to pass bounded script to another user so he can add it to his own spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From [Quickstart: Macros, Menus, and Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros) I know how to add my script to my spreadsheet:

**Tools > Script editor**, **Blank Project**, *delete any code in the script editor and paste in the code*.

it called **bounded script** ([Scripts Bound to Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)).

but what if I need to pass (already written) script to another user, so that user would be able to apply this script to his own spreadsheets?

Comment: @teatimer ye, or add that script to original spreadsheet by myself. But what if that person have another files where he could use the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to share the code or let them edit, you could use a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries). All sheets must have the code

in the bounded script:

```
function onOpen(){
  libraryName.createMenus();
}
```

That's it, you'll have access to all methods that you display in the `createMenus()`, these which should also call the `function` with the `libraryName` identifier behind it, as such:

```
  var fun = 'libraryName.'
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Load funcs').addItem('first func', fun+'anyFunc').addToUi();
```

And for debugging add the library to itself.

Also he can use any `function` by calling `libraryName`, it even shows in autocomplete all functions in the library.

Comment: Note that library code is still easy to access and copy. It just protects your copy from edits.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu, how do you copy all the library code just with the identifier and no access?

Comment: You click on Resources > Libraries, then on the library title, opening a tab with its documentation. In this tab URL you can easily grab the library KEY. With this key you just grab any script URL and replace it `https://script.google.com/macros/d/<<KEY>>/edit`. The library will open normally in "view" mode, since the library must be share with at least view only with the user in order for one to use it.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu `[...] library must be share with at least view only[...]`, didn't know that.